# UI/UX design feels like waterfall, What do you think should be the proper process?

Tags: agile, user-experience, ui, react, waterfall

I'm currently working as Fullstack developer, our frontend is being built in React.

Our current process involves:

1. The client / product owner describes a feature to the UI / UX designer.
2. The designer creates a nice template in Figma, or any other UI tool like-so
3. The design is given to us the developers to implement
4. The code is written, then QA'd, any differences between the design and the product are flagged as bugs

That's fine a dandy for small features, but let's say we want to write a DateTime selector, as you might know, these are complex components, so ideally we want to look at existing components that are open source and solve our problem.

But is going to be really hard, even with advanced tweaking to make a built component look like your design, and building the component from scratch is an ardous task.

So my ask is, What is the proper course here? Should we (as developers) grind our teeth and create the component? Should we send back the design? Or try to match with an existing component and diminish the inadecuacies between the built component and the design?

Comment: That _is_ waterfall. You've tagged this [tag:agile] but in what you've described the only feedback cycle is UI/UX diffs -> bugs. Do the devs have input to the design process in terms of what's _feasible_ (e.g. what components are in libraries already in use)? Do you and QA have a shared understanding with design and the stakeholders about what's _important_ in the template, vs. what might just be nice-to-have? Do you have any mechanism to _iterate_ towards a good-enough implementation rather than spending effort on fixing "bugs" that the stakeholder may not even care about?

Comment: The proper course is to ask your team (which includes all the roles you mentioned). Strangers from the internet are unlikely to know how your team can improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe doesn't feel like waterfall - it is waterfall. One of the twelve principles of Agile Software Development is that "business people and developers must work together daily throughout the project". Today, the phrase "business people" is interpreted to mean project and product managers, which often include user experience designers. Your current process doesn't the key stakeholders working together in a collaborative environment.

From an agility standpoint, the recommendation would be to get more people involved earlier. People with expertise in development and test would be involved potentially as early as talking to the client or product manager, but certainly by the time the UI design was being created in your UI mockup tools. The UX designers, developers, and testers would have real-time conversations about trade-offs between existing components in a component library, open-source components, and the effort to build and test custom components and what the best options are to satisfy the stakeholders. The collaboration would continue through the release, with everyone involved at every step of the way.

However, no one here can tell you if this way of working makes sense for your organization or team. There may be organizational impediments that prevent this highly collaborative way of working, and until those are resolved, you may have to have other mitigations for the risks associated with working sequentially and having hand-offs and late testing.

Comment: Hmm...  My idea of "Waterfall" is Big Design Up Front - Gather requirements for a month or two, build the software, and then have the customer tell you at the end of the development process that it wasn't really what they wanted.  My last project had weekly meetings with the stakeholders for design and review, and it went just fine.  It might not have been "agile"  from a purist's perspective, but we certainly didn't consider it "waterfall."

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not classic waterfall, but probably waterfall with subprojects or staged delivery with sequential activities within the stages. Even if it's not waterfall at the level of the effort, the described design process is a waterfall. It could be Scrumerfall, for example, if the design process ends with something more like Scrum for delivery.

Comment: We worked in two-week sprints, more or less.  We didn't meet every day with the Business Analysts, however.

Comment: *"business people and developers must work together daily throughout the project"* - I never understood this as an obligation for making daily meetings, only as an option in case there are open questions or things to discuss. But sometimes, there is not much to discuss for a week which cannot be collected and asked later.

Comment: @DocBrown That's how I've interpreted it as well. It means that the people work together as necessary, making the decision on if and how to collaborate, daily. There's no throwing work over the wall where a team goes away for a while and comes back with work. All of the key stakeholders are available for each other.

Answer (score 0):

Agile would say do an iteration with the quick off the shelf component and add more stories, each estimated for where it falls short of the desired goal.

The problem is this relies on the customer, internal or external, buying into the core idea of any Agile methodology. That half a solution has value.

If your customer wants the exact design and nothing else, then they haven't bought into that idea. You can still internally iterate but there will be a disconnect between your internal agile process and what you show the customer.

So, your question boils down to "What is the best process to produce something with immutable specifications?" The answer is Waterfall. People use Agile because they know that for lots of problems, an early partial solution has value and a late perfect solution has no value.

I believe that that tenet has been proven and you should use an agile methodology for the component in your example. Your customer *will* find value in a partial solution. The only question is whether your relationship with them is structured in a way which allows them to blame you for the shortfall.